# XML to CSV (Generation of New Date with input Date)

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a requirement in which I have to generate new date(YYYYMMDD) from the date which is coming in the record(YYYYMMDD) and below is logic for New date creation:

1.If 'MM - 1' = 0, Then make MM -'12', and Year value as YearFromActualDate - 1
2.DD is always '01'
3.If 'MM - 1' != 0, Then MM in output will be 'MM - 1' and Year will remain the same
I have mentioned the Expected Output which will give idea of above mentioned logic.
Please advise.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
<xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
<xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:text>Name</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$delim" /> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:text>Date</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:text>NewDate</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$break" /> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ID/ED/E1" /> 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="E1">
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />   
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />  
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
    <xsl:variable name="newdate" select="'01'" />
    <xsl:variable name="inMonth" select="substring(date,5,2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="inputYear" select="substring(date,1,4)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test = "$inMonth='01'">
            <xsl:variable name="calculatedMonth" select="12"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(xs:integer($inputYear) - 1,$calculatedMonth,$newdate)" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="inMonthlength" select="string-length(xs:string(xs:integer($inMonth) - 1))" />
            <xsl:if test="xs:integer($inMonthlength) !=2">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($inputYear,concat(0,xs:integer($inMonth) - 1),$newdate)" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="xs:integer($inMonthlength) =2">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($inputYear,(xs:integer($inMonth) - 1),$newdate)" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="$quote"/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="$break" />    
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Input:

```
   <ID>
   <ED>
   <E1>
   <name>Eva</name>
   <date>20190504</date> (Consider date as YYYYMMDD)
   </E1>
   <E1>
   <name>Alan</name>
   <date>20190101</date>
   </E1>
   </ED>
   <ID>
```

Expected Output:

```
     "Name","Date","NewDate"
     "Eva","20190504","20190401"
     "Alan","20190101","20181201"
```

Comment: Well, XSLT/XPath 2 and later have the `xs:date` data type which supports date arithmetics and component extraction https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#dates-times so create `xs:date`s from your `date` element values with e.g. `xs:date(replace(., '([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '$1-$2-$3'))` and implement your logic to create the other dates and format them using `format-date`.

Comment: May I ask if could please provide implementation on how to write in XSLT , as I do not have that much command in XSLT as of now . On the basis of input date I have to generate new date...with logic's.

Comment: Well, the functions you need are documented, so start learning to use them by reading the docs and writing some code. You will not get any command in any language if you don't try to write code yourself.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for your guidance. I have created the XSLT and updated as well for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If I've reverse-engineered your algorithm correctly, what you want is the first day of the previous month.

Logically the steps are:

1. Convert your date to an xs:date value
2. Take the first day of the current month
3. Subtract one month.

In practice it's simplest to combine (1) and (2) so you end up with

```
xs:date(replace($date, '(....)(..)(..)', '$1-$2-01')) - xs:yearMonthDuration('P1M')
```

and then you can format this date as YYYYMMDD using

```
format-date($date, '[Y0001][M01][D01]')
```